# Image over iframe in html

Tags: html, image, iframe, sharepoint, overlay

I need to create a little html code that I will use in sharepoint in script editor. The idea is that I have some report from Microsoft BI in iframe (changed the address in code below) and it works fine. But I want to cover the "share buttons" in the bottom right of the site, so it can't be shared. The iframe should fill the whole WebPart in sharepoint, so I tried to allign the image simply to bottom right corner, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>


        <iframe src="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=x5UEWO-yGaOh8welvY2IAQ"  width="100%" height="700">
        </iframe>
        <img src="logo.jpg" align="bottom" align="right">

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally got it working. The "TOP" variable is static, it's the height of the displayed website minus the height of the image itself. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<div style="height:750px; position:relative">
<iframe style="border:none; width:100%; height:700px; z-index:1" src="website.com"></iframe>
<img style="top:663px; right:0px; position:absolute; z-index:9" src="testbar2.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The align attribute of `<img>` is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

```
img {
 float: right;
}
```

Comment: Ok, it's aligned to the right now. But it's not covering the iframe it looks like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/5522/Lri6qO.png

Comment: Sorry for double post. The bottom grey line should overlay the buttons above it. Right now it's just rendered in the next line

Comment: If you want just to hide the share buttons, why you don't select them by class, for example, and give them : `.shared-buttons {display: none}` ?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't really work. According to analysing the code, the name is this:

<i class="glyphicon pbi-glyph-share glyph-small icon"></i>

I tried to use i.glyphicon.pbi-glyph-share.glyph-small.icon {display: none}

but it doesnt work. Any advice?

Comment: I think your code for selection is fine, but can not tell what is the reason for not working. Maybe some CSS specificity, what will happen if you add `!important`?  See if `display: none` is applied at all, or is overwritten by something else. The other thing you can do, is to give some margin-top to the element with the grey line, or bigger z-index than the image (see what z-index is for) in order to overlap the image.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use layers, but it doesn't work - somehow. I got it sort-of working once, but it was alligned to left and I couldn't move it.